# what's wrong with sqlite 3 ? I have just added libsqlite3 file and my database created by manager then

Tags: sqlite

What's wrong with sqlite 3 ? I have just added libsqlite3 file to my framework and my databasae to my resources folder created by manager... then my application is not opening. report, relaunch options screen appears although i did not do anything with the sqlite3 ..  Is it time to try my app in real iphone ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information, there's no way to know what is going on, but I'll answer the only question I see.

**Nothing**. SQLite3 has worked fine for me in the past, therefore I have to conclude that the issue isn't with SQLite3 but instead an issue with your application.

If you post what language/platform/frameworks/etc. you're using, possibly along with some sample code, we'd all be able to be much more helpful.

Comment: I am using objective c, XCode IDE, Cocoa environment.. libsqlite3.dylib has the size of 60 kb. And sometimes I download sample codes and those do not work becuase they give general error like : " There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphoneos2.1' " (sometimes instead of iphoneos2.1, it says higher versions) So, It seems to me that my problem may be related to inconsistency.. Why does it happen although I have iphone device sdk 3.1.2. And before importing my database and framework, everthing was fine. It is not code-related actually.

Comment: I Found my fault .. I am importing an dynamic lib somthing downloaded from anywhere . I had to import lib from my iphoneosX.Y sdk .. Sorry for that

Comment: No problem. Glad to hear you figured it out.